# Cakephp 3 Formhelper input : how to add a css class attribute

Tags: formhelper

I'm trying to add a css class attribute to a field but i have a small problem :

```
echo $this->Form->input('dateLimite', ['type'=>'text', 'foo' => 'bar', 'class' => 'datepicker']);
```

Output :

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="dateLimite" foo="bar" required="required" id="datelimite">
```

The class attribut cannot be displayed. Have you an idea please ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess you're using [Holt59's Bootstrap 3 helpers](https://github.com/Holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap3-helpers). There's a bug in that code that overwrites the classes you set, and replaces those classes with `form-control`.

The guy I sit next to at work, [@matt-stephens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1598113/matt-stephens), just had a fix for that merged into the repo, so if you update it, your class should appear as expected. Testing locally:

`echo $this->Form->input('dateLimite', ['type'=>'text', 'foo' => 'bar', 'class' => 'datepicker']);`

Now gives:

`<input type="text" name="dateLimite" class="form-control datepicker"  foo="bar" class="datepicker" id="datelimite" />`

[Here's the merge request](https://github.com/Holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap3-helpers/commit/647bcc296bb43b44fd7eb20e109e8ec3c06be29a).